# Get value form two tables with different fields,and unique values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have  two tables app_test1 and app_test2 
 in app_test1

```
billdt       tracknum   ups_netchg
10/25/2015   221        455
10/25/2015   222        245
10/25/2015   223        123
10/25/2015   224        888
```

in table 2 app_test2

```
billdt       tracknum   optic_netchg
10/25/2015   221        456
10/25/2015   222        890
10/25/2015   223        345
10/25/2015   226        987
```

now i want  like this.

```
billdt       tracknum   ups_netchg  optic_netchg
10/25/2015   221        455         456
10/25/2015   222        245         890
10/25/2015   223        123         345
10/25/2015   224        888         NULL
10/25/2015   226        NULL        987
```

My code is like this :

```
select test.billdt,test.tracknum,

IfNull(app_test1.ups_netchg,0) as ups_netchg,
IfNull(app_test2.optics_netchg,0) as optics_netchg

from (
select app_test1.tracknum, app_test1.billdt

from app_test1 union

select app_test2.tracknum, app_test2.billdt from app_test2 ) as

test
left join app_test1 on test.tracknum = app_test1.tracknum
left join app_test2 on test.tracknum = app_test2.tracknum
```

i am learning mysql . show i know there is lots of another way to get this result .first i want to know is the above code is correct. Is there any other way to write that query more short if yes please share it .

Comment: You have written this query correctly. You may want to include `ORDER BY 1, 2` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in MYSQL full outer join not working the alternate way which i use is as

```
SELECT * FROM ot_app_test1 left outer join app_test2 on app_test1.tracknum = app_test2.tracknum
union
SELECT * FROM ot_app_test1 right outer join app_test2 on app_test1.tracknum = app_test2.tracknum
```

Try it

Comment: i tried it and it working , i think  you just change the way. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The `union` with two joins is one way to implement a `full outer join`.  It does, however, incur a lot of overhead because the `union` is eliminating a lot of duplicate records.

An alternative method is to get the list of keys first and then use `left join`.  The duplicate elimination is done on a smaller set:

```
select billdt, tracknum, t1.ups_netchg, t2.optic_netchg
from (select billdt, tracknum from app_test1 union
      select billdt, tracknum from app_test2
     ) bt left join
     app_test1 t1
     using (billdt, tracknum) left join
     app_test2 t2
     using (billdt, tracknum);
```

Or, in your case, because there are no duplicates that generate multiple rows:

```
select billdt, tracknum, max(ups_netchg), max(ups_netchg2)
from (select billdt, tracknum, ups_netchg, NULL as ups_netchg2
      from app_test1
      union all
      select billdt, tracknum, ups_netchg, NULL as ups_netchg2
      from app_test2
     ) tt
group by billdt, tracknum;
```

If performance is at all an issue, I would try all three approaches to see which works best in your case.